# Validate if parameter is equal to one of the given conditions - nullable input given. The null is a valid condition too

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to validate/check if the parameter `x.Size` is equal to one of the given conditions above.

The issue is that `Size` is `string[]?` and `conditions.Contains(x);` expects x to be non nullable string. By the way, if `Size` is null, should be a valid condition too.

`public string[]? Size { get; }`

```cs
public sealed class GetProductsQueryValidator : AbstractValidator<GetProductsQuery>
{
    public GetProductsQueryValidator()
    {
        var conditions = new List<string> { "m", "l", "s" };

        RuleFor(x => x.Size)
            .Must(x => conditions.Contains(x)) // compile-time error: x is expected to be non nullable
            .WithMessage($"Please only use: {string.Join(",", conditions)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood your question before the edit to mean that Size was a string that can be null. Now you're saying it's an array of string. My question is: can `Size` itself be null, or just items of `Size`? Given `string[]?` I'd think that the array itself can be null but not the items. Is that wrong?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, `Size` is valid when it is "null", "m", "l", "s", otherwise it is not. Its type is `string[]?`.

Comment: So really it's `public string?[]? Size { get; }` ?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, no. https://i.imgur.com/2cDIDhJ.png

Comment: I'm confused. `public string[]? Size { get; }` states that the array itself can be null, but that the items are not. `public string?[] Size { get; }` states that the array items can be null, but that the array itself is not. `public string?[]? Size { get; }` states that the array can be null, and so can the items. No?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, in other words the user may have not provided `string[]`, that's why it is nullable.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, oh I think I got your point now. The size values itself should be: "m", "l" or "s". But size property can also be left empty be the user. That's why it is `string[]?`

Comment: I've edited my answer to what I believe you want (`Size` can be null, or an individual item can be `null` if Size isn't null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.When` for this:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Size)
    .ForEach(i => i
        .Must(iv => conditions.Contains(iv!))
        .WithMessage($"Please only use: {string.Join(",", conditions)}")
        .When(iv => iv != null)
    )
    .When(x => x.Size != null);
```

Note that we need to apply a condition for each array item using `ForEach`.

That way it will only evaluate the condition when Size isn't null, and only evaluates the item condition when the item isn't null.

Comment: `x` inside `Contains` is still giving `Cannot resolve method 'Contains(string[]?)', candidates are: bool Contains(string) (in class List<string>) bool Contains<TSource>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource) (in class Enumerable)`

Comment: Please note that the null condition should be valid too.

Comment: @nop Please provide the definition for `GetProductsQuery` then... You didn't tell us so I assumed `Size` was a `string`.

Comment: `public string[]? Size { get; }`